# ImportError: No module named parse python/node js

Tags: python, node.js

I am calling .py file from node.js using `npm i cmd-node` on windows it is working well and executing my .py file from .js file,  but when I am deploying it on the server giving following error:

Note: I am not importing parse anywhere, it may be part if any dependency.

```
python script cmd error: Error: Command failed: python covert_to_csv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "covert_to_csv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tabula
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tabula/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .wrapper import (
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tabula/wrapper.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .file_util import localize_file
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tabula/file_util.py", line 3, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import urlparse as parse_url
ImportError: No module named parse
```

Comment: Most likely an error because mixing Python 2 and Python 3 code and interpreters. Fix your Python installation and pass explicitly path to your Python interpreter in JS code.

Comment: `from urllib.parse import urlparse as parse_url` is the Py3 import but you are the running on Py2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using different versions of python on your local machine compared to the server. Make sure it is the same version as your local machine and it'll work.